Lower bounding the inner product between two functions given information about boundary values and monotonicity.
Given f, g $\in L^2([0, 1]) \cap \mathcal{C}^1([0, 1])$. Suppose we know that $||f||_2 = ||g||_2 = 1, f(0) = g(0), f(1) = g(1), f' \geq 0$ and $g' \geq 0$. How sharply can we control the lower bound of the inner product $\langle f, g\rangle$?
I don't have many concrete tools about this kind of problem, this is a problem come to my mind when I was randomly drawing some pictures. My intuition tells me that it should not be 0 which is a trivial lower bound.

The lower bound can be as close to $-1$ as you like:
Define
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases} -1 + \frac{2}{n^2}x^2 & \text{ if } x \in (0,1/n)\\
+1 & \text{ if } x \in (1/n,1)
\end{cases}
$$
and $g_n(x) = -f_n(1-x)$.
Then $f_n \to 1$ and $g_n \to-1$ in $L^2$ and $(f_n,g_n) \to -1$.
One has to scale these functions to get $\|f_n\|_{L^2}=\|g_n\|_{L^2}=1$, but the scaling factor has to  tend to $1$ since $\|f_n\|_{L^2} \to 1$.

Thank you very much!
